# Next JS - How to modify SVG properties values and add nodes?

Tags: javascript, node.js, typescript, svg, next.js

I'm using SVGR to load a SVG as a component, in my next js 13 app :

```
import CvSvg from './../../public/image.svg'

export default function Home() {
    return (
        <div className="flex flex-col min-h-screen">
            <CvSvg />
        </div>
    )
}
```

Let's imagine I have this element in the SVG :

```
<tspan
         sodipodi:role="line"
         style="font-size:4.93889px;fill:#000000;stroke:none;stroke-width:0.264583;stroke-opacity:1"
         x="79.525864"
         y="29.664894"
         id="tspan59991">message
</tspan>
```

How can I edit the text "message", or any properties such as its position, color etc from the code ?
Also, how can I add some nodes, to add a line after the "tspan" node for example ?

I've tried by many ways, I tried this for example, but it didnt work, the line wasn't showing up :

```
import { useEffect, useState } from 'react';
import SVG from './public/image.svg'

function Home() {
  const [svgDoc, setSvgDoc] = useState(null);

  useEffect(() => {
    fetch(SVG)
      .then(response => response.text())
      .then(data => {
        const parser = new DOMParser();
        const svgDoc = parser.parseFromString(data, "image/svg+xml");

        const text = svgDoc.querySelector('#tspan59991');

        const line = svgDoc.createElementNS('http://www.w3.org/2000/svg', 'line');
        line.setAttribute('x1', '79.525864');
        line.setAttribute('y1', '30.664894');
        line.setAttribute('x2', '90');
        line.setAttribute('y2', '30.664894');
        line.setAttribute('style', 'stroke:#000000;stroke-width:1');

        text.parentNode.appendChild(line);
        setSvgDoc(svgDoc.documentElement.outerHTML);
      });
  }, []);

  return (
    <div className="flex flex-col min-h-screen">
      <div dangerouslySetInnerHTML={{ __html: svgDoc }} />
    </div>
  );
}

export default Home;
```

Comment: In principle, you are on the right track. But `<line>` is not allowed as a child element of `<tspan>`, only of [container elements](https://www.w3.org/TR/SVG11/intro.html#TermContainerElement)

Comment: I'm using text.parentNode.appendChild(line);... so parentNode doesnt retrieve the parent node of "tspan", so the container ? it retrieves the parent of the attribute which has id #tspan59991 ?

Comment: You are right, I didn't notice the `parentNode`. This would be the `<text>` element, not a container element as listed in the link of my first content.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could turn the SVG into a React component and then render whatever you want from props, state, etc.:

```js
function App() {
  return (
    <Demo subhead="this is a subhead" />
  )
}

function Demo ({subhead}) {
  return (
    <svg viewBox="0 0 100 100">
      <text x="0" y="20">
        <tspan>message</tspan>
      </text>
      <text x="0" y="40" fill="red">
        <tspan>{subhead}</tspan>
      </text>
    </svg>
  )
}

ReactDOM.render(<App />, document.getElementById('root'))
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.6.3/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.6.3/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>

<div id="root"></div>
```